# Draw a graph with the given properties or if no such graph exists, explain

Tags: graph-theory

Draw a graph with the given properties or if no such graph exists, explain

1. simple graph with six vertices of degree $2,2,2,4,5,5$
2. simple graph with 7 edges, 9 vertices each of degree at least 1.

I thought to use Handshaking Lemma to prove those but failed to apply. An undirected graph should contain an even number of vertices of odd degree. Here it holds for 1st problem.  Don't know how to prove them. Help please.

Comment: For the first one, just try to draw it. Start with 6 vertices, and draw the edges of the degree-5 vertices (because that's the easiest). What happens? Can you finish? If you can, good. If you can't, why not?

Comment: @Arthur Not possible to draw, as to make degree 5 to two vertices only, it makes degree of all other 4 vertices 2. If I went to make one of them degree 4, degree of other 3 vertices increased. But how to write?

Comment: You have it written already. What you have there is basically a full answer to the first problem. Maybe it ought to a sentence or two longer for readability and clarity, but the argument is complete.

Comment: @Arthur and the 2nd please...

Answer (score 1):

2 is possible and in fact there are several ways to do it. Just add the 7 edges one by one and try to satisfy the condition as early as possible - it's difficult to go wrong.

1 is not possible. Often when working with simple graphs, if there are a lot of edges it's easier to work with the complement. The complement must have degrees $3,3,3,1,0,0$; now two vertices are irrelevant and it shouldn't be hard to see why the remaining four can't work.